# Generate a responsive grid made of nodes in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

So im trying to make a pathfinding visualizer and i can't figure out how to generate a grid that will have as many nodes as the screen size allow instead of an hardocoded value. I generate the nodes in this way:

```
*ngFor="let n of generateNodesGrid(6000); let i = index"
```

Where the method return an Array of the argument size.

In the scss file i try to create a grid:

```
:host {
display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(2.5rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(2.5rem, 1fr));
}
```

But with angular im strulling to figure out which components height will be used to be auto fitted.
So the generated nodes are too many or too few based on the screen size.

Comment: What happens when you press F12 and try to debug that host style?  I suspect the 2.5em values are preventing what rou want. You can also try reducing fr amounts too.

Comment: it's a bit bigger than the grid on top and the sides and the same dimension on bottom

Comment: Are you able to tweak it to your liking?  You should have full control in debug mode.

Comment: Also just so you know 6000 nodes is excessive.  I think I've read in the past that around 1500 is max recommendation.

Comment: uhm im not sure i can make a grid with only 1500 nodes they would be very big. So any other way to make a such grid? it has to become kinda a maze.